# How do I test someone else's code from Github?

Tags: github

I'm on my very second project on Javascript and I came across several people's codes on Github. I'd like to give them a test run to understand how they work. How or what is the best way to go about testing the code?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a repository in GitHub, there's a Green "Code" dropdown menu in the repository page (see screen shout).

You can use this menu to clone\download the repo to your local computer and play with it

[image]